# Capitalise the first letter of multiple sentences, lower-case all else

Tags: python, string

Update: I am interested in multiple sentences in one string.

I have been following this handy [tutorial](https://thispointer.com/python-capitalize-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string/), that offers variations of my requirements.

**How can I capitalise just the first letter of multiple sentences?**

Sentence being either of the three: `. ! ?`.

---

**Code:**

[PDF, pg 3](https://ungc-production.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/attachments/cop_2016/290831/original/GPIC_Sustainability_Report_2016-v9_%28lr%29.pdf?1465251381)

```
from io import StringIO

from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage

def convert_pdf_to_string(file_path):
    output_string = StringIO()
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as in_file:
        parser = PDFParser(in_file)
        doc = PDFDocument(parser)
        rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
        device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, output_string, laparams=LAParams())
        interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
        for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
            interpreter.process_page(page)

    return(output_string.getvalue())

text = convert_pdf_to_string('GPIC_Sustainability_Report_2016-v9_(lr).pdf')
print(text)
```

`text`:

```
In 2012, Gulf Petrochemical InDuStRiEs Company becomes part of \nthe global transformation for a sustainable future by committing to \nthe United Nations Global Compact’s ten principles in the realms \nof Human Rights, Labour, Environment and Anti-Corruption. \n\nGPIC becomes an organizational stakeholder of Global Reporting \nInitiative ( GRI) in 2014.
```

**Desired Text:**

```
In 2012, Gulf Petrochemical Industries Company becomes part of the global transformation for a sustainable future by committing to the United Nations Global Compact’s ten principles in the realms of Human Rights, Labour, Environment and Anti-Corruption. GPIC becomes an organizational stakeholder of Global Reporting Initiative ( GRI) in 2014.
```

**Update Code:**
Can be added anywhere

```
text = text.replace('\n', '')
text = text.replace('\x0c', '')
```

Please let me know if I should clarify anything else.

Comment: I guess your main problem there will be finding sentences. It's done very easily in case there is just one symbol as a sentences separator (let's say — a period `.`), but when there 3 of them (`. ! ?`) it gets a bit more complicated. :) 

I'd recommend to provide example source/output texts containing all 3 separators, to make this detail clear.

Comment: I'll update post shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'This is An ExAmplE senTENCE.'
s.capitalize()
>> 'This is an example sentence.'
```

Try this:

```
from nltk import tokenize
paragraph = "Hello there. How are you?"
sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(p)
capitalized = [s.capitalize() for s in sentences]
new_paragraph = ''.join(capitalized)
```

Comment: example = "This is an ExMaPlE SeNtEnCe. Many More" | example.capitalize() >>> `'This is an exmaple sentence. many more'`

Comment: The example was only one sentance, ill add an answer for multiple sentences, one second

Comment: Multiple sentence gets tricky in case you have words with acronyms and stuff.
`I am from F.B.I.` `Hi ! How are you`. It adds extra complexity to the problem if you want to cover those cases

Comment: If it has a `. ` then a spacing of any kind (space, tab, newline) etc

Comment: @StressedBoi69420 Try the code I just posted, I haven't tested it but should work. You will need to import the nltk library https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.html

Answer (score 1):

```
'.'.join([i.capitalize() for i in s.split('.')])
```

for many sentences ^